# Notificaciones con PHP

Tags: php

Hola chicos como hago que me aparezca una alerta cuando la solicitud https no encuentra la identificación en una base de datos mediante el uso de una api rest 
Lo que estoy haciendo es buscar una identificación cuando la encuentra me muestra en una tabla dicha información también un pdf, pero cuando no lo encuentra igual me muestra la tabla y el pdf vacío(Probé por consola me retorna un null) lo que quiero es bloquear esa tabla y el pdf y solo me muestre una alerta "Identificación no existe". Gracias por su respuesta.

Codigo PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$ruc=$_POST['ruc'];


$url = 'https://......'.$ruc;
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$datos = json_decode($json,true);

$rucs=$datos["NUMERO_RUC"];
echo'<br>';
echo'<div class="c">';
    echo '<table class="table">'
    .'<tr style="text-align:center">'
    .'<td style="background:#EEE"><b>Número de ruc</b></td>'
    .'<td style="background:#EEE"><b>PDF</b></td>'
echo '<tr style="text-align: center">'
        .'<td>' . $rucs. '</td>'
        .'<td>' . '<a href="pdf/pdf.php">PDF</a>'. '</td>'
echo '</table>';
echo'</div>';
}
```

Comment: if(count($rucs)>0){echo "viene mas de uno";}else{echo "viene  vacio";}

Comment: Amigo igual me muestra la tabla vacia, me puedes ayudar talvez estoy colocando mal tu linea de código

Comment: prueba con $rucs=$datos->NUMERO_RUC

Comment: coloque tu linea de codigo despues de $datos=json... asi : elseif(count($ruc)<0){ $rucs =$datos["NUMERO_RUC] pero ahora no me muestra la tabla

Comment: creo que lo mejor seria hacer var_dump($datos);exit() para ver como va el json

Comment: amigo ya te escribí al tu correo puedes revisar mi código. Gracias

Comment: hola Andres y @IgmerRodriguez. Ya que estais en una plataforma para preguntas y respuestas con comentarios para conversar, no creo que plantearla y luego irse a un medio de conversacion privado sea lo oportuno. Esta pregunta servirá no solo para vosotros si no para futuros usuarios. Si requeris hablar más se puede crear una sala de chat enlazada a la pregunta para ese fin y esa sala perdurará para el resto de usuarios que quieran leerla.

Comment: Y si haces un `if (!$rucs){codigo mostrando error} else { codigo mostrar tu tabla}`

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($datos);` reproduciendo un caso en que tengas que mostrar que no hay datos. Puede que la API responda con alguna clave en el JSON en esos casos y lo más conveniente sería verificar esa posible clave de error.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes evaluar si existe $rucs, si existe muestras la tabla, si no existe escribes el código javascript que lance un alert(), o lo que desees, así:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$ruc=$_POST['ruc'];


$url = 'https://......'.$ruc;
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$datos = json_decode($json,true);

$rucs=$datos["NUMERO_RUC"];

if(!$rucs){
  echo '<script>alert("No se ha encontrado el identificador")</script>';
}else{
  echo'<br>';
  echo'<div class="c">';
  echo '<table class="table">'
    .'<tr style="text-align:center">'
    .'<td style="background:#EEE"><b>Número de ruc</b></td>'
    .'<td style="background:#EEE"><b>PDF</b></td>'
  echo '<tr style="text-align: center">'
    .'<td>' . $rucs. '</td>'
    .'<td>' . '<a href="pdf/pdf.php">PDF</a>'. '</td>'
  echo '</table>';
  echo'</div>';
  }
}
```